# Могу ли я вставлять hr между li?

Tags: html, html5

Не так страшно выставлять горизонтальную линию тегом hr между пунктами li списка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё супер получается, не нужно терять время и использовать рамку, псевдоклассы или рисовать линию через css. Только вот W3C ругается на такое. Почему нет? Что не так?

Comment: Если вам нужно отделять элементы списка друг от друга, то, может, это на самом деле не один, а три разных списка?

Comment: Это не для заказа, я сайт делаю для себя. Мне просто интересно: уместно ли использовать такой приём  в вёрстке?

Comment: Не уместно. Так как разрешенним сожержимым является ноль или больше `<li>` элементов, которые содержат вложенные элементы `<ol>` или `<ul>`. С этой информацией можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Comment: «Уместно» звучит как субъективная характеристика — может, кто-то считает уместным писать некорректный html-код :) Но я (субъективно) думаю, что любой некорректный html-код (код, не соответствующий актуальной спецификации) стоит считать неуместным

Comment: Понял, спасибо!